# Execution order of Inherited class and @FindBy class

Tags: java, selenium, testng

We use **@FindBy** annotation for get web element using Page Object Modeling concept.

e.g.

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//input[@type='text'][@placeholder='Search']")
WebElement searchBox;
```

but in order to get `searchBox` element we need to call `PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);` first and then after we can perform actions on that element.

I have designed framework accorfing below.

*Parent Class:*

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

import core.driver.WebDriverManager;

public abstract class BasePO {

    static {
        System.out.println("Static Block");
    }

    BasePO() {
        System.out.println("initElements");
        initElements();
    }

    private void initElements() {
        PageFactory.initElements(getDriver(), this);
    }
}
```

*Child Class:*

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;

public class TestPO extends BasePO{
    @FindBy(css = "input[title='Search']")
    WebElement searchBox;

    @FindBy(css = "input[value='Google Search']")
    WebElement searchButton;

    public void sendKeys(String inputText){
        searchBox.sendKeys(inputText);
    }

    public void clickOnSearchButton(){
        searchButton.click();
    }
}
```

*Test Class:*

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import core.pageobject.TestPO;

public class TestClass{
    @Test
    public void test123() {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.gsmarena.com/");
        TestPO tpo = new TestPO();
        tpo.search("iphone 7");
    }
}
```

If I run the test case: `test()` then according to me executions steps would be:

1. Firefox driver created [in TestClass]
2. Web site will open in firefox browser [in TestClass]
3. `@FindBy` annotations would be called first or loaded in memory (I think it's lazy loading) [in TestPO]
4. Static Block [in BasePO]
5. initElements [in BasePO]
6. **WebElement** of searchbox can be accessed and **sendKeys** action can be performed on that [in TestClass]

But if I am not correct then when `@FindBy` annotations would be called and what would be the execution order

Comment: Why not try put debug points on all the above. And get to see the execution order it that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Execution order will be:

1. Firefox driver created [in TestClass]
2. Web site will open in firefox browser [in TestClass]
3. Static Block [in BasePO]
4. initElements [in BasePO]
5. `@FindBy` annotations would be initialized(Initialization defined in PageFactory.java) [in TestPO]
6. WebElement of searchbox can be accessed and sendKeys action can be performed on that [in TestClass]